# Sending message after non authenticate trying to access

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a message if non authenticate user trying to access authenticate URL

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
  {
    return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
           : redirect()->guest('/');
  }
```

It redirects to `/` login but how do i show message in `/` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sessions.

In your controller-

```
use Session;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
  {
    Session::put('error_message','Please login to continue.');
    return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
           : redirect()->guest('/');
  }
```

In your blade file-

```
@if(Session::has('error_message'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('error_message') }}</div>

  @php
    Session::forget('error_message');
  @endphp

@endif
```

**UPDATE**

Create session key only if redirection is to be done. If only JSON is expected, then we need to skip session part.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
  {
    if($request->expectsJson()){
       return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
    }
    Session::put('error_message','Please login to continue.');
    return redirect()->guest('/');
  }
```

Comment: @Hola Thanks for accepting. I have made a small update just to let you know.